# Transform vectoriel equation having a dot product into a linear equation

Tags: vector-spaces

I have this 3D vectoriel equation: $\overrightarrow{D}={\overrightarrow{B_2A_2}*\alpha +\overrightarrow{A_1B_2}} - {(\overrightarrow{A_1B_1})\bullet(\overrightarrow{B_2A_2}\alpha +\overrightarrow{A_1B_2}) \over \|\overrightarrow{A_1B_1}\|^2} *(\overrightarrow{A_1B_1})$

The 3D points $A_1$, $B_1$, $A_2$, $B_2$ are the constants in the equation and $\alpha$ is the variable. 
As I'm not very familiar with mathmethic symbols, here is my vision:

- The big dot ($\bullet$) represents the dot product between two 3D vectors: $x_1*x_2 + y_1*y_2 + z_1*z_2$
- The asterix ($*$) represents either:

  - a multiplication of two 3D vectors: $\overrightarrow{a}*\overrightarrow{b}=(a_xb_x; a_yb_y; a_zb_z)$
  - a multiplication of a 3D vector with a constant: $\overrightarrow{a}*c=(a_xc; a_yc; a_zc)$

I would like to transform the equation in a classical linear form: $\overrightarrow{D}=\overrightarrow{a}\alpha + \overrightarrow{b}$ to find the value of $\overrightarrow{a}$ and $\overrightarrow{b}$. How can I proceed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will use that the dot product is *bilinear* for real vectors, i.e. that
$$
(\overrightarrow{a}+\alpha*\overrightarrow{b})\bullet\overrightarrow{c}=\overrightarrow{a}\bullet\overrightarrow{c}+\alpha*\overrightarrow{b}\bullet\overrightarrow{c},
$$
and that
$$
\overrightarrow{a}\bullet(\overrightarrow{b}+\alpha*\overrightarrow{c})=\overrightarrow{a}\bullet\overrightarrow{b}+\alpha*\overrightarrow{a}\bullet\overrightarrow{c}
$$
for all vectors $\overrightarrow{a},\overrightarrow{b},\overrightarrow{c}\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and scalars $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. Using this fact we can rewrite your equation as follows:
\begin{align}
\overrightarrow{D}&=\overrightarrow{B_2A_2}*\alpha+\overrightarrow{A_1B_2}-\frac{\overrightarrow{A_1B_1}\bullet(\overrightarrow{B_2A_2}*\alpha+\overrightarrow{A_1B_2})}{\|\overrightarrow{A_1B_1}\|^2}*\overrightarrow{A_1B_1}\\
&=\overrightarrow{B_2A_2}*\alpha+\overrightarrow{A_1B_2}-\frac{\alpha*\overrightarrow{A_1B_1}\bullet\overrightarrow{B_2A_2}+\overrightarrow{A_1B_1}\bullet\overrightarrow{A_1B_2}}{\|\overrightarrow{A_1B_1}\|^2}*\overrightarrow{A_1B_1}\\
&=\overrightarrow{B_2A_2}*\alpha+\overrightarrow{A_1B_2}-\left(\alpha*\frac{\overrightarrow{A_1B_1}\bullet\overrightarrow{B_2A_2}}{\|\overrightarrow{A_1B_1}\|^2}+\frac{\overrightarrow{A_1B_1}\bullet\overrightarrow{A_1B_2}}{\|\overrightarrow{A_1B_1}\|^2}\right)*\overrightarrow{A_1B_1}\\
&=\left(\overrightarrow{B_2A_2}-\frac{\overrightarrow{A_1B_1}\bullet\overrightarrow{B_2A_2}}{\|\overrightarrow{A_1B_1}\|^2}*\overrightarrow{A_1B_1}\right)*\alpha+\left(\overrightarrow{A_1B_2}-\frac{\overrightarrow{A_1B_1}\bullet\overrightarrow{A_1B_2}}{\|\overrightarrow{A_1B_1}\|^2}*\overrightarrow{A_1B_1}\right).
\end{align}
In your notation, we thus see that
\begin{align}
\overrightarrow{a}&=\overrightarrow{B_2A_2}-\frac{\overrightarrow{A_1B_1}\bullet\overrightarrow{B_2A_2}}{\|\overrightarrow{A_1B_1}\|^2}*\overrightarrow{A_1B_1},&\overrightarrow{b}&=\overrightarrow{A_1B_2}-\frac{\overrightarrow{A_1B_1}\bullet\overrightarrow{A_1B_2}}{\|\overrightarrow{A_1B_1}\|^2}*\overrightarrow{A_1B_1}.
\end{align}

Edit: I copied the original equation incorrectly, and that has now been fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It gives me some tips how to proceed but the initial equation you use is not correct. My equation contains vectors $\overrightarrow{A_1B_2}$ and $\overrightarrow{A_1B_2}$ which doesn't exist in your equation.

Comment: @Saelhenen Oh sorry, I messed that up. For completeness' sake, I have now fixed it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've transformed the equation on my side before you edit and I got the same answer as you. Note: you can remove the part where you explain $\overrightarrow{a}\bullet\overrightarrow{a}=\|\overrightarrow{a}\|^2$ in your answer as it is not used anymore ;)